# Multidimensional array to 2 dimensional in php

Tags: php

Is it possible to easily go from multidimensional array to 2 dimensional without looping through it in php? like [key,[key2,value]] to [key,value] that is from

```
$tstAry = array("a"=>array(1,"alpha"),"b"=>array(2,"beta"));
```

to

```
$tstAry2 = array("a"=>"alpha","b"=>"beta");
```

i tried playing with array_keys and array_values but couldn't combine it correctly

Answer (score 2):

```
$tstAry2 = array_combine(array_keys($tstAry), array_column($tstAry, 1));
```

This got me the desired result, is there an easier way or this is it? like [][1]

Comment: No, there's no simpler way. That's why `array_column` was added.